# Change label text on particular option selected from combobox in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need something if particular option selected in combobox then label text should be changed which will be pre defined. E.g. If I select Option A then label should display 10 & if select Option B then labele shows 15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Create a combobox that has two items. One with value 10 and text "A" and other with value "15" and text "B"

Step 2: Now create selectedIndexChange event for combobox.

Step 3: Inside selectedIndexChange event write the code to set the label text with {comboboxID}.SelectedValue